# Custom Search Results in REST MarkLogic

Tags: rest, xslt, marklogic

So new to MarkLogic am stuck and not finding the documentation of use. I know what i need to do, just do not know how to do it.

I have a keyvalue? search on my REST server which returns ML's standard search results and XML snippet. I want to create my own custom search result which will output a title element for my XML files.

I am aware that i need to create an XSLT transformation document and upload that to the server but do not know how to target ML's search function or how to write this out.

I have basic knowledge of XSLT, if i just created something that targets each files title using xPath will this work, or does ML require use of their custom functions?

I know its a bit broad, but hopefully someone can point steer me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you are talking about the [GET /v1/keyvalue](https://docs.marklogic.com/8.0/REST/GET/v1/keyvalue) endpoint of MarkLogic REST API. Unfortunately that does not allow you to choose a transform. You can probably use [GET /v1/search](http://docs.marklogic.com/REST/GET/v1/search) with a transform param instead though, using a structured query for an element value query. The docs contain a good [syntax reference](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/structured-query#id_59265) on that.

Docs on creating and managing transforms can be found here:

http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/rest-dev/transforms#chapter

HTH!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`extract-metadata`](http://docs.marklogic.com/search:search#opt-extract-metadata) in your search options with `search:search` or the [`/v1/search/` REST API endpoint](http://docs.marklogic.com/REST/GET/v1/search) to include the title element in a metadata element or JSON property in your results:

```
import module namespace search = "http://marklogic.com/appservices/search"
  at "/MarkLogic/appservices/search/search.xqy";

search:search(
  "my query string",
  <options xmlns="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search">
    <extract-metadata>
      <qname elem-ns="" elem-name="title"/>
    </extract-metadata>
  </options>)
```

If you need more flexibility, you specify a [custom snippet implementation](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/query-options#id_58295) or a [results decorator function](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/query-options#id_35434) in your search options.

Comment: this is so close to what i need, my final issue is that i need to have a condition where the results are only returned if an element with a specific attribute exist. I have tried using constraint but it is not working. Ultimately i need /v1/keyvalue to return my custom search, or my element/attribute search to limit my results.

Comment: Do you know the possible values of the attribute? If so, you could pass an array of values to a value query: http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/structured-query#id_39758. If not, you probably need to tweak your data model. In Marklogic, you can check the existence of an element with `cts:element-query($qname, cts:and-query(()))`, but there's no way to check the existence of an attribute with a `cts:query`.

Answer (score 0):

Is this key-value or full text? For key-value you could use XPath. Any XPath that starts with `/` or `//` or `fn:collection()` or `fn:doc()` will search the entire database. You can search specific document(s) or collection(s) too.

For full text you'd probably want to use https://docs.marklogic.com/search:search - or possibly https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:search for really low-level control.

There's some example code using `search:search` from XSL at https://github.com/marklogic/RunDMC which might help. It doesn't use the REST API: it's a traditional form-submit web page. But the `view/search.xsl` code might give you some idea how to call the search API from XSLT.

That RunDMC code might also help you if you need to call XSL from XQuery: take a look at `controller/transform.xqy`.